# Perl5Util regex matching

Tags: java, regex

I am using Apache Velocity, to generate xml, which uses [Perl5Util](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.apache.velocity/velocity/1.6.3/org/apache/velocity/app/event/implement/EscapeReference.java#EscapeReference.referenceInsert%28java.lang.String%2Cjava.lang.Object%29) to match entities that need to be xml escaped. I am trying to come up with a regex that will match everything but the word "style". Based on the [Perl5Util doc](http://jakarta.apache.org/oro/api/org/apache/oro/text/regex/package-summary.html) I came up with

```
new Perl5Util.match("/(?!style)/", "style");
```

Unfortunately that seems to return true for "style" and any other words I try. Could anyone lend me a hand with figuring out a regex that would work?

The Apache Velocity doc includes some [examples](http://click.apache.org/docs/velocity/developer-guide.html#Configuring_Event_Handlers), but all of those are for including terms, not excluding.

Comment: @JackManey I am generating XHTML with Velocity. I don't want Velocity to escape my stylesheet, so I am using the `eventhandler.escape.xml.match` property. `style` is a variable that is part of the VelocityContext. Nowhere am I trying to parse XML with a regex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must add an anchor:

```
new Perl5Util.match("/^(?!style)/", "style");
```

Comment: Thanks. This worked except I had to also match the `$` for the Velocity reference. So I had to use `/^(?!\\$style)/`